# Deploy jhipster on Weblogic stuck at weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner

Tags: java, spring, oracle, weblogic, jhipster

I'm strying to deploy jhipster to weblogic, everything seen ok since there is no error have been thrown but deployment process fall in loop `(self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner`

full log here:

```
017-04-18 09:55:12.082 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Starting Swagger
2017-04-18 09:55:12.090 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] i.g.j.c.apidoc.SwaggerConfiguration      : Started Swagger in 7 ms
2017-04-18 09:55:12.993  INFO 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] com.baoviet.login.ApplicationWebXml      : Started ApplicationWebXml in 25.687 seconds (JVM running for 20847.862)
2017-04-18 09:55:13.598  INFO 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] o.g.t.server.TyrusServerConfiguration    : Found programmatic endpoints:
        io.undertow.websockets.jsr.annotated.AnnotatedEndpoint

2017-04-18 09:57:08.699 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : StoreCleaner for weblogic.wsee.server.WsStorage@324494c timer popped
2017-04-18 09:57:08.699 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : Now checking persistent state objects
2017-04-18 09:57:08.699 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : StoreCleaner(weblogic.wsee.server.WsStorage@324494c) - persistent store empty.
2017-04-18 09:59:08.700 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : StoreCleaner for weblogic.wsee.server.WsStorage@324494c timer popped
2017-04-18 09:59:08.701 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : Now checking persistent state objects
2017-04-18 09:59:08.701 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : StoreCleaner(weblogic.wsee.server.WsStorage@324494c) - persistent store empty.
2017-04-18 10:01:08.701 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : StoreCleaner for weblogic.wsee.server.WsStorage@324494c timer popped
2017-04-18 10:01:08.702 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : Now checking persistent state objects
2017-04-18 10:01:08.702 DEBUG 18174 --- [ (self-tuning)'] weblogic.wsee.server.StoreCleaner        : StoreCleaner(weblogic.wsee.server.WsStorage@324494c) - persistent store empty
```

Database: Oracle
State: running and no locks (everthing ok)
Start in develop mode: running without any error

Anyone had been deploy jhipster to weblogic can help me or notice some must have configuration?

Comment: `io.undertow` seems suspicious when deploying in weblogic, don't you hink you should exclude undertow from dependencies?

Comment: I didn't exclude it since it's a part of spring-boot but i''ll give it a try